# Viewpager getCurrentItem() do not invoke for first and last page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In viewpager the pagedapter method  getcurrentItem() is not called for first and last page. while scrolling.

Scenario : When i loaded the adapter for the first time .

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Log.d("CurrentItem", ""+mPager.getCurrentItem());
        Log.d("CurrentPosition", ""+position);

        mFragNamLabel.setText("SCREEN "+(mPager.getCurrentItem()+1));
        return SCOrderButtons.newInstance(position);
    }
```

getcCurrentitem() is called two times at the time on initialization , and it is not called for first and last page . How this actually works ?